# Some pixels of the drawn triangle are not within the triangle's vertices

Tags: c, framebuffer, rasterizing

I made a quad, that rotates around the Y axis and at some parts of the rotation some of the pixels extend past the triangle's side and form a line. This is a picture of the lines I am talking about - http://0x0.st/oOYp.png. This might be a floating point error or a rounding problem in the code, but I am unsure if that can cause this many pixels. This seems to only happen with the top of the quad. This is the tutorial I followed for the triangle rasterization - http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/java/TriangleRasterization/TriangleRasterization.html. This is the full code - https://pastebin.com/zhA8U6cp. This is the flat top triangle drawing loop (All of the variables are floats except `i` and `framebuffer`):

```
currentxleft = bottom[0];
currentxright = bottom[0];
slopeleft  = (bottom[0] - left[0])  / (bottom[1] - left[1]);
sloperight = (bottom[0] - right[0]) / (bottom[1] - right[1]);
for(i = bottom[1]; i > left[1]; i--){
   for(j = currentxleft; j <= currentxright; j++){
      fragmentshader(incolor, outcolor);
      framebuffer[i * width + j] = (255 << 24 | ((int)outcolor[0] * 255 & 0xFF) << 16 | ((int)outcolor[1] * 255 & 0xFF) << 8 | (int)outcolor[2] * 255 & 0xFF);
   }
   currentxleft -= slopeleft;
   currentxright -= sloperight;
}
```

And this is the bottom flat triangle drawing loop:

```
currentxleft = top[0];
currentxright = top[0];
slopeleft  = (left[0]  - top[0]) / (left[1]  - top[1]);
sloperight = (right[0] - top[0]) / (right[1] - top[1]);
for(i = top[1]; i < left[1]; i++){
   for(j = currentxleft; j <= currentxright; j++){
      fragmentshader(incolor, outcolor);
      framebuffer[i * width + j] = (255 << 24 | ((int)outcolor[0] * 255 & 0xFF) << 16 | ((int)outcolor[1] * 255 & 0xFF) << 8 | (int)outcolor[2] * 255 & 0xFF);
   }
   currentxleft += slopeleft;
   currentxright += sloperight;
}
```

This is the declaration and definition of the variables:

```
float top[2];
float left[2];
float right[2];
float currentxleft;
float currentxright;
float slopeleft;
float sloperight;

float bottom[2];
float left[2];
float right[2];
float currentxleft;
float currentxright;
float slopeleft;
float sloperight;

if(v1[1] < v2[1] && v1[1] < v3[1]){
   top[0] = v1[0];
   top[1] = v1[1];
   if(v2[0] < v3[0]){
      left[0] = v2[0];
      left[1] = v2[1];
      right[0] = v3[0];
      right[1] = v3[1];
   }else{
      left[0] = v3[0];
      left[1] = v3[1];
      right[0] = v2[0];
      right[1] = v2[1];
   }
}
if(v2[1] < v3[1] && v2[1] < v1[1]){
   top[0] = v2[0];
   top[1] = v2[1];
   if(v1[0] < v3[0]){
      left[0] = v1[0];
      left[1] = v1[1];
      right[0] = v3[0];
      right[1] = v3[1];
   }else{
      left[0] = v3[0];
      left[1] = v3[1];
      right[0] = v1[0];
      right[1] = v1[1];
   }
}
if(v3[1] < v1[1] && v3[1] < v2[1]){
   top[0] = v3[0];
   top[1] = v3[1];
   if(v1[0] < v2[0]){
      left[0] = v1[0];
      left[1] = v1[1];
      right[0] = v2[0];
      right[1] = v2[1];
   }else{
      left[0] = v2[0];
      left[1] = v2[1];
      right[0] = v1[0];
      right[1] = v1[1];
   }
}
```

Comment: You answered my (retracted) answer with "I made changes" after copying the source. Download the (presumed to work) original source again. Use `diff` or `fc` to discover/analyse your changes.

Comment: Why the flat-top and flat-bottom drawing code here? The top of the rect clearly isn't flat. You've got a quad made up of 2 of what the article you've linked covers in the "general case". Also, the article's flat-top code draws from bottom to top (scanLine--), yet yours draws from top to bottom (j++). I'd imagine there are similarly glaring mistakes, but don't have time to look right now. I suggest you do away with the fragment shading part for the time being (to simplify the code and make mistakes more obvious) and copy the code more closely until you've a working example. Add shading after.

Comment: @enhzflep The tutorial I linked explains how to draw any triangle. I just need to split it to be one flat top triangle and one flat bottom triangle. I am drawing the triangle exactly how the tutorial does it. The `j` variable is used in the loop, that draw lines from the left side of the triangle to the right side. It is not used in the tutorial, as they use a drawLine function and it is not included in their code.

Comment: I am using two loops in my code - one to draw from top to bottom in the case of the flat bottom triangle and draw from bottom to top in the case of the flat top triangle and one to draw the lines from left to right.